# освобождение памяти с++

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы, матрицы

есть функция в ней я выделяю память под массив x, провожу вычисления, далее возвращаю

```
double* kramer(double** mat, double* y, int size) {
    double d = det(mat, size);
    double* x = new double[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        x[i] = det(get_mat(mat, y, i, size), size) / d;

    return x;
}
```

потом в основной программе вызываю функцию

```
double* p_x = kramer(m, y, s);
```

и удаляю p_x

```
delete[]p_x;
```

Вопрос: у меня высвободится память из под массива x, которую я выделял в функции?

Comment: да, освободится.

Comment: вангую, что `get_mat ()` тоже выделяет память, которая не освобождается...

Comment: да, вы правы, только вот как его удалить? Создать указатель на эту функцию и потом через него удалить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Операторы `delete` и `delete[]` оперируют адресами, которые им передаются в качестве указателей. Значение указателя `x`, полученное через `new[]` из функции возвращается и присваивается переменной `p_x` т.о. они хранят одинаковые адреса. А значит `delete[]` отработает именно на том адресе, который вернул `new[]`.

Для самостоятельной проверки можете убедиться в эквивалентности адресов с помощью отладчика. Понятно, что до выхода из функции значение `x` нужно будет где-то запомнить, так как он станет недоступен в отладчике для непосредственного сравнения с `p_x`.

Answer (score 0):

Освободится, потому что ты и удаляешь массив `х`. `p_x` - это лишь указатель на массив `x`, а не новый массив

Comment: спасибо большое